# Read xml file/string in a generic way without knowing the structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq, generics

I want to read a XML hierarchy into a tree of in-memory objects. The XML tree could have n-levels of children. I do not know the exact number. My in-memory objects have a children and parent property to be bound to a tree control.

How can I read xml file/string in a generic way into my in-memory objects when I do not know how the xml element tags are called/written exactly?

For example someone could provide me a xml structure of units where each unit has many units etc... so I know the xml tag is "unit" but it could be "module" too or anything else... it must work generic but I do not what to ask the user entering the xml element tag name like "unit".

Is that possible at all what I want to achieve?

Comment: You seem to be describing the concept of a DOM. Your generic in-memory objects with children and parent properties sound exactly like DOM nodes.

Comment: My in-memory objects are ViewModels being the datasource for a treeview control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way, you have to know the node name to parse the hierarchy at least you have to have a definition. IMHO, `XElement` is the only sort of generic `XML` parser around. For instance, you have a XML like this:

```
<module name="core">
    <modules>
        <module name="xml">
            <modules>
                <module name="reader" />
                <module name="writer" />
            </modules>
        </module>
        <module name="json">
            <modules>
                <module name="serializer" />
                <module name="deserializer" />
            </modules>
        </module>
    </modules>
</module>
```

As I said earlier, you should have some definitions like the `root node` must the hierarchical element name and the children container must be `root node name + s`. This is one simple way that you can allow your users to specify any node names they wish but with some constraints.

You may parse the `XML` using `XElement` like this:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Load(@"path\to\your\xml\file");
string rootNodeName = xElement.Name.LocalName;
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = xElement.Descendants(rootNodeName + "s");
```

And of course you can `Linq` the `xElements` and to parse the hierarchy you can recur to build your tree control.

You may take a kick start on xElement with these links below:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/xelement
- [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0541__XML-LINQ/0040__XElement.htm)
- http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/

Hope this helped.

Comment: I know .Descendants and it looks your code will work ;-) I will follow your suggestion: rootNodeName + "s"); thats ok for me i think NOW!

Answer (score 1):

I would just load it into `XmlDocument` and then build the tree going through `XmlNodes`.

Comment: @Jakuk if I do not know the customers xml file and its structure it would be madness just to read each node and assume I do everything correct... above all from where would I know the xml element tags name?

Comment: @msfanboy - either you know the node names and want to read only them, or you don't know them and you want to read whole file. There's no other way. You asked `how to read xml file in a generic way when nodes are not known`. If you want a different answer ask a different question

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible to achieve what you want to achieve.  I'd do it something like this:

```
class GenericNode
{
  private List<GenericNode> _Nodes = new List<GenericNode>();
  private List<GenericKeyValue> _Attributes = new List<GenericKeyValue>();
  public GenericNode(XElement Element)
  {
     this.Name = Element.Name;
     this._Nodes.AddRange(Element.Elements()
                                 .Select(e => New GenericNode(e));
     this._Attributes.AddRange(
                Element.Attributes()
                       .Select(a => New GenericKeyValue(a.Key, a.Value))
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public IEnumerable<GenericNode> Nodes
  {
    get
    {
       return this._Nodes;
    }       
  }
  public IEnumerable<GenericKeyValue> Attributes
  {
    get
    {
       return this._Attributes;
    }
  }
}

class GenericKeyValue
{
  public GenericKeyValue(string Key, string Value)
  {
     this.Key = Key;
     this.Value = Value;
  }
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(StringOfXml); // or
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(FileOfXml);

GenericNode rootNode = new GenericRode(rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XmlTextReader](http://www.noboxsolutions.com/xmltextreader_constructor.aspx) and at the package [`System.Xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). This articles will help you too:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/XMLReadWrite.aspx
- http://www.noboxsolutions.com/xmltextreader_constructor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
using System.Xml ;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    using ( Stream inputStream = OpenXmlStream() )
    {
      XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument() ;
      document.Load( inputStream ) ;
      Process( document ) ;
    }
  }
  static Stream OpenXmlStream()
  {
    // provide an input stream for the program
  }
  static void Process( XmlDocument document )
  {
    // do something useful here
  }
}
```