# Reading a XML, in which the tags are not known

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML Document which is generated from an external program. In that the Tag names are not known. is there a way to read this and convert it to LINQ? (Sorry if this dsnt make any sense :/ )

Comment: You can read tag names, but what query you want to convert to linq?

Comment: @Frank59 : well the whole need to do this is i need to convert an XML to a Excel orksheet

Comment: I think you need to know some convert criterias such are tag names and document strucutre for that

Comment: please visit:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881396/read-xml-file-string-in-a-generic-way-without-knowing-the-structure