# Convert childnodes to properties of class

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have to read xml file.
every xml file is different.
I want to bind it to a datagrid, for doing that I want to convert it to an observable collection but for this I have to create a class with properties like childnodes.

for exmple, the xml file:

```
<book>
   <name>book1</book>
   <author>author1</author>
</book>
<book>
   <name>book2</book>
   <author>author2</author>
</book>
```

now I want to convert it to a class

```
public class Book
{
    public string name;
    public string author;
}
```

and than create an observableCollection that containes the books.

How can I do it???

Comment: What do you mean by saying "every file is different"? Is there always a book-structure like the posted one or could it be something like "car" in some file?

Comment: It could be completely other structure or the same structure but with additional properties

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881396/read-xml-file-string-in-a-generic-way-without-knowing-the-structure